# Как в chrome extension очистить историю?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь создать расширение где можно удалить историю конкретной вкладки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вкладки нет истории. Можно только всю историю чистить. Посмотрите в api, в хистори нет ни `tabId` ни вообще чего-то связывающего историю с владкой.

```
chrome.history.deleteAll(function callback)
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-deleteAll

И не забудьте в манифесте поставить в `permission` `history`

Comment: Она удаляет всю историю. Нужно использовать функционал позволяющий конкретезировать запрос.

Comment: Да, поправил ответ. Вообще вам придется тогда хранить у себя историю всех вкладок, и потом `chrome.history.search` по урлам.

Comment: какую функцию мне в скобки вставлять?

Comment: Какую напишете, такую и вставляйте. Но вам до этого ещё далеко, сначала надо написать хранилище, собирать информацию по chrome.tabs status complete. И только после этого приступить к chrome.history